# This is my first Express server but I don't know why POST, PUT and DELETE is not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, server, backend

I wrote this in express JS. the 2 GETs are working but the remaining are not working but I can't see what's wrong with the code. I have a .json file in my directory where I am calling the data from. When I use get id, i get the correct id. When I use POST, it will post only the _id and Date without posting the body of the data.

```
    const studentsArray = readFile();
    const studentId = studentsArray.find(student => student._id == req.params.id)

    if (studentId) {
        res.send(studentId)
    } else {
        res.status(404).send("student not found")
    }
});

router.get("/", (req, res) => {
    /* const studentsArray = readFile(filePath); */
    res.send(readFile())
});

router.post("/", (req, res) => {
    const studentsArray = readFile()

    /* const emailCheck = studentsArray.find(student => {
        if (students)
    }) */
    const newStudent = { ...req.body, _id: studentsArray.length + 1, createdOn: new Date() };
    studentsArray.push(newStudent)
    fs.writeFileSync(filePath, JSON.stringify(studentsArray))
    res.status(201).send(`Student ${newStudent._id} was Created Successfully`)

});

router.put("/:id", (req, res) => {


    const studentsArray = readFile();

    const editedStudent = studentsArray.find(student => student._id == req.params.id) 

    if (editedStudent)
   { 
    const mergedStudent = Object.assign(editedStudent, req.body)
    const position = studentsArray.indexOf(editedStudent) 
    studentsArray[position] = mergedStudent  
    fs.writeFileSync(filePath, JSON.stringify(studentsArray))
    res.send(mergedStudent)
} else {
    res.status(404).send("Student not found")
}

});

router.delete("/:id", (req, res) => {
    const studentsArray = readFile();
    const studentsRemains = studentsArray.find(student => student._id != req.params.id)
    if (studentsRemains.length < studentsArray.length) {
    fs.writeFileSync(filePath, JSON.stringify(studentsRemains))
    res.status(204).send("Deletion successful")
    }
    else {
        res.status(404).send("Student Not Found")
    }
});
```

Comment: Do you have body-parser added to your express server? You need to add that middleware. https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/body-parser.html It would help if you posted your express setup code.

Comment: @bhmahler Body Parser has it's own issues. Use express.urlencoded(extended: true) and express.json() as middlewares.

Comment: do you get any error ?

Comment: Thank you all, I got it now. I have to change the position of my express.json to the top of router.